# Read a pdf file from a url and POST it on another server using python requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I have tried the code below. Doesn't work.
The PDF is readable in browser.
I want to GET the pdf file from the GET-url and POST it to another server.

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url='some url')
requests.post(url='my_url', files={'file':response.content})
```

Link: (Expired)

Comment: What response have you got?

Comment: if I print "response.content", it displays a text "'This site is currently under maintainance. || Incident Time: 2019-03-11 13:11:22 UTC || Incident ID : -----XIZeeoGF0tV9FvI0Rs7LBAAABB8-----'
" But the PDF is working in the browser.

Comment: Can you share a link to PDF?

Comment: I have added the link to the question

Comment: Did you try `response.text`? `response.content` is used to access the response body as bytes according to the Requests Quickstart documentation. maybe the pdf is encoded as ASCII text file.

Comment: I’ve tried response.text, same issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by a missing header, specific the Uses-Agent. Looks like the site checks it.
The call returns a HTTP 406 (response.status_code). With the header a HTTP 200 is returned.

Try this:

```
import requests
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url='some url', headers=header)
requests.post(url='my_url', files={'file':response.content})
```

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes!